# Android query error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id,lastname,status FROM people WHERE " + "id = "+ IncomingiD +" FROM people WHERE status =100 ); ",null);
```

I want to access to "status=100 and id=incomingid" of my people table. I wrote above snipped code but I am getting an error below.... What is wrong with that query ? Could you please help me ?

```
E/Error(996): Error while openining peopleandroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT id,lastname,status FROM people WHERE  id = 1 FROM places WHERE status =100 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `FROM people` part twice in your query :

- First, at the correct place, between the select and where clause
- And then, a second time, after the first condition in the where clause.

Also, note that you have `where` twice in your query -- the two condition should be separated by and `and`, and not a second `where`.

Oh, and it also seems that you have a closing `)` at the end of your query?

Basically, your query looks like this :

```
SELECT id,lastname,status 
FROM people 
WHERE id = ....
FROM people 
WHERE status =100 
);
```

But it should be looking like that :

```
SELECT id,lastname,status 
FROM people 
WHERE id = ....
    and status = 100
```

In the end, I'm guessing your Java code should look a bit like this :

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id, lastname, status FROM people WHERE id = " + IncomingiD + " AND status = 100",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query should read

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id,lastname,status FROM people WHERE " + "id = "+ IncomingiD +"AND status =100 ); ",null);
```

Comment: @Co Koder - that would be because he left out `+ "` after IncomingiD.

Answer (score 0):

your query is wrong. there can be only one FROM in sql statement.

try this:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id,lastname,status FROM people WHERE " + "id = "+ IncomingiD +" AND status =100 ); ",null);
```